Reconsider adding Markdown support for footnotes
A 2009 feature request to add support for Markdown footnotes was declined in 2014.
The reason(s) for declining appear to no longer be valid:

We want to avoid creating proprietary additions to Markdown

Stack Exchange already supports additions to the CommonMark specification, such as tags, spoilers, syntax highlighting for code, and tables. See, for example, the announcement of table support from 2020, which explicitly acknowledges this and says that the GitHub-flavored markdown table extension is "stable and usable enough to serve our purpose".
Since the CommonMark specification has already been extended and GitHub-flavored Markdown is already in use, it no longer seems valid to claim that there is a desire to avoid proprietary extensions or additions to the CommonMark specification. The use of the GitHub-flavor extension for footnotes is no different than the use of GitHub-flavor extension for tables.

We do not have consensus that footnotes are something to be encouraged

We can check based on the voting of this question, but the original feature request question and the vast majority of the answers have a net-positive score today. Only two answers claim that the feature is unnecessary - the accepted answer (which also outlines a workaround) and one answer scored at -2.

A work-around exists (albeit an ugly one)

The workarounds are only partial. Although you can use HTML tags to create superscript text, the workarounds and comments on them point out issues with user experience, readability, and navigability. In addition to human readability improvements (in both the Markdown editor and the rendered output), this also opens the possibility to mark the content for machine readability and denoting content.
Implementing this feature can assist with better ways to reference material written by others, such as some sites encouraging or requiring more formal citations of content that are difficult to do in-line. Across the network, it can give authors a better way to put supporting or clarifying content without interrupting the flow of the key points of the answer.

Would also remove the need for suboptimal hacks to sort of get footnotes

Great idea! Footnotes that behave like bi-directional links would be a great bonus :)

@Joachim That's a good point. It's very hacky to do a one-way link to a footnote, that may even break because of someone else's answer. But having bidirectional links would be better supported with footnotes in Markdown. I suppose someone's answer could still break them, but if implemented properly, I'd consider someone breaking the anchors to be disruptive behavior.

@ThomasOwens that's not trivial since scrolling to the right anchor is done by the client-side browser and scrolling distance can depend on the size of surrounding headers and other elements. If you have links in spoilers/summaries the browser might also not support it (this has been controversial because accessibility/screen readers), so while the CommonMark spec may suggest it's possible to have bi-directional links they can require careful adjustment of the JS/CSS by the devs. There's more to it than just expanding the CommonMark parser since SE hasn't allowed anchors in headings either.

@ThomasOwens I can see it now, the NSFW hacker writing colorful anchors having them appended to the SE domain. It would be a laugh :)

We're not talking space tech, browsers can already do this. And have had the capability for decades. It's fragments: <a hreaf="#note1-footnote" to jump down to the footnote, <a hreaf="#note1-source" (with appropriate IDs applied on the source/footnote elements) to jump back. The browser then handles the jump to the named elements. Yes, a markdown consumer needs to be changed to generate this. But that's going to be the case whatever you really want to do - nobody is "withholding" markdown features. They just need to be added.

@VLAZ then try nesting that or putting it inside summaries/spoilers to see if it works. Plus keeping it consistent between edits.
